# ASP Classic How to change the length of an array that is held by another array (not true 2d array)

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm need to be able to have a 2d array, where the length of second array varies on a case by case basis. To this end, I made an array that contains other arrays with the following code:

```
 Dim timeline
    ReDim timeline(days)

    for reDate = beginDate to endDate 
        timeline(DateDiff("d", beginDate, reDate)) = Array(0)
    next
```

The problem I am having is that I am unable to change the size of any of the arrays contained by timeline, as ReDim doesn't seem to work when I do this. Does anyone know how I would go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Does not work" and error messages ("Object required") without code/context are not the best way to ask a question. The first is a complete waste of time; the second may indicate that you used `Set` where you shouldn't (VBScript Arrays are not objects, so there shouldn't be any `Set` in the code).

This demonstrates the same facts that @omegastripes pointed out, but gives hints wrt possible pitfalls:

```
Option Explicit

Dim AoA : AoA = Split("s o m e|w o r d s|o f|d i f f e r e n t|l e n g t h", "|")
Dim i
For i = 0 To UBound(AoA)
    AoA(i) = Split(AoA(i))
Next
WScript.Echo "----- test data:"
For i = 0 To UBound(AoA)
    WScript.Echo Join(AoA(i), "")
Next
WScript.Echo "----- array assignment copies (For Each elem ... does not 'work'):"
Dim e
For Each e In AoA
    e = "zap"
Next
For Each e In AoA
    WScript.Echo Join(e, "")
Next
WScript.Echo "----- array assignment copies (change needs index access):"
For i = 0 To UBound(AoA)
    e = AoA(i)
    e(0) = UCase(e(0)) ' just changes the copy (e)
    WScript.Echo Join(e, "")
    AoA(i)(1) = UCase(AoA(i)(1)) ' access via indices changes org collection
    WScript.Echo Join(AoA(i), "")
Next
WScript.Echo "----- replace whole subarrays (re-dimensioned dynamically):"
Dim n, m
For i = 0 To UBound(AoA)
    e = AoA(i)
    n = UBound(e)
    ReDim Preserve e(n * 2 + 1)
    For m = n + 1 To UBound(e)
        e(m) = UCase(e(m - n - 1))
    Next
    AoA(i) = e ' replace whole element
    WScript.Echo Join(AoA(i), "")
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 37951664.vbs
----- test data:
some
words
of
different
length
----- array assignment copies (For Each elem ... does not 'work'):
some
words
of
different
length
----- array assignment copies:
Some
sOme
Words
wOrds
Of
oF
Different
dIfferent
Length
lEngth
----- replace whole subarrays:
sOmeSOME
wOrdsWORDS
oFOF
dIfferentDIFFERENT
lEngthLENGTH
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below snippet, **using `a` as temporary array variable**:

```
Dim timeline, a
ReDim timeline(days)

' initial fill the array
For reDate = beginDate to endDate
    a = Array()
    ReDim a(99)
    timeline(DateDiff("d", beginDate, reDate)) = a
Next

' redim sub arrays
For reDate = beginDate to endDate
    ' assign subarray to a
    a = timeline(DateDiff("d", beginDate, reDate))
    ' redim a
    ReDim Preserve a(199)
    ' put changed array into root array
    timeline(DateDiff("d", beginDate, reDate)) = a
Next
```

In this case each subarray contains 100 elements first, and 200 after redim.

Comment: Wouldn't each subarray be a, so i would have days copies of a, rather than days unique subarrays? How would I resize each individual a after they were assigned? I'm not sure it matters, because I got an Object Required on a when I tried to check it anyway haha